# Getting an aggregate value from a subquery with group by

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate the rate of customer survival for 12, 24, 36 etc months (i.e., the number of still active customers/total customers). The problem is that "total customers" has to be "customers who are at least as old as the period tested" (e.g., how many customers who have started at least 12 months ago are still active after 12 months).

I have three relevant columns:

- PROD_CDE = product line
- START_DATE = start date
- END_DATE = leave date

And I have tried the following code:

```
select PROD_CDE, 
    (SELECT sum(CASE WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, END_DATE) > 11) then 1 else 0 END)/count(START_DATE) where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, NOW()) > 11) AS survival_12m,
    (SELECT sum(CASE WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, END_DATE) > 23) then 1 else 0 END)/count(START_DATE) where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, NOW()) > 23) AS survival_24m,
    (SELECT sum(CASE WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, END_DATE) > 35) then 1 else 0 END)/count(START_DATE) where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, NOW()) > 35) AS survival_36m,
    (SELECT sum(CASE WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, END_DATE) > 47) then 1 else 0 END)/count(START_DATE) where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, NOW()) > 47) AS survival_48m,
    (SELECT sum(CASE WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, END_DATE) > 59) then 1 else 0 END)/count(START_DATE) where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, NOW()) > 59) AS survival_60m,
    (SELECT sum(CASE WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, END_DATE) > 71) then 1 else 0 END)/count(START_DATE) where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, NOW()) > 71) AS survival_72m,
    (SELECT sum(CASE WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, END_DATE) > 83) then 1 else 0 END)/count(START_DATE) where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, NOW()) > 83) AS survival_84m,
    (SELECT sum(CASE WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, END_DATE) > 95) then 1 else 0 END)/count(START_DATE) where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, NOW()) > 95) AS survival_96m
from TABLENAME 
where START_DATE >= '2011-01-01' 
group by PROD_CDE;
```

I get this error message:

```
Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'local.TABLENAME.START_DATE' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

I have checked several other related questions but not been able to find a solution yet.

Comment: Try to do it without brackets: `sum(...)` instead of `(select sum(...))`

Comment: I tried that originally. The problem is that each subquery has its own "where" clause matching the period length (e.g., ...where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, ORG_DATE, NOW()) > 11)). If I do as you suggest I would be including customers who are not "old" enough to have had the opportunity to survive yet in the denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation directly:

```
SELECT PROD_CDE, 
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, LEAST(END_DATE, NOW())) > 11) / SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, NOW()) > 11) AS survival_12m,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, LEAST(END_DATE, NOW())) > 23) / SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, NOW()) > 23) AS survival_24m,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, LEAST(END_DATE, NOW())) > 35) / SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, NOW()) > 35) AS survival_36m,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, LEAST(END_DATE, NOW())) > 47) / SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, NOW()) > 47) AS survival_48m,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, LEAST(END_DATE, NOW())) > 59) / SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, NOW()) > 59) AS survival_60m,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, LEAST(END_DATE, NOW())) > 71) / SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, NOW()) > 71) AS survival_72m,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, LEAST(END_DATE, NOW())) > 83) / SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, NOW()) > 83) AS survival_84m,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, LEAST(END_DATE, NOW())) > 95) / SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, NOW()) > 95) AS survival_96m
FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE START_DATE >= '2011-01-01' 
GROUP BY PROD_CDE
```

Comment: Thanks but same problem as mentioned above: The denominator is supposed to only include customers who have had the opportunity to survive (i.e., they must be at least as old as the respective period lengths). That's why each subquery in the original code has its own "where" clause.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think this can be right (although it will be approximately right). Wouldn't SUM be the sum of months and not sum of customers?

Comment: `SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, END_DATE) > 11)` sums the boolean expression `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, END_DATE) > 11` which is either 1 (true) or 0 (false). So it is equivalent to: `sum(CASE WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, END_DATE) > 11) then 1 else 0 END`. This is a feature of MySql.

Comment: Considered me schooled :) Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it's still not correct. The reason is that END_DATE can be in the future. So, now the numerator can be too large because it includes cases that could not be included in the denominator. I still think a where clause like in my original code is necessary.

Comment: You can use the function LEAST(). See my edited answer.

Comment: That's nice! The numbers look right now. Thanks again!